# Spring Boot Rest Controller - Is it possible to use a custom annotation to filter the request before processing it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-restcontroller

I have a number of controllers in my application, and want to be able to annotate each method in the controllers to denote what level of permission is required to access that request.

**For Example**

```java
@RestController
class MyController {

    @Permission("MyC_R")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", produces = "application/json" method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> list(final HttpServletRequest req) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ... fluff omitted for brevity



        return new ResponseEntity(body, rh, hs);
    }
}
```

We are using JWT tokens that contain the permisisons for the user. What we would like is to be able to pass that parameter `MyC_R` to the `@Permission` annotation - (meaning MyController/Read), and then check to see if that user has the permission in their JWT. I already have a class that extracts that and checks the users permissions - I just need a way to invoke this before the request, so that I can return a 401 UNAUTHORIZED header to the front end if this should happen.

I looked at using AOP, but that seems to be more all-encompassing of the controllers. I need to be able to apply this with a specific /per-controller-per-method/ parameter.

Will the annotation get processed before? If the permissions check fails IN the annotation, is it possible to send a response to the front-end without even going into the method?

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but Spring Security already does exactly what you want with `@PreAuthorize` (and `@PostAuthorize`)

Comment: We already looked into that - and it does not provide the necessary measures we want to implement

Answer (score 1):

You can and should use AOP. You can definitely pass arguments to your annotation to set permission level per metod.

Define an interface as follows:

```
@Retention(...)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Permission {
   String permissionLevel();
}
```

Then define your implementation

```
//This code gets executed before the controller code.
@Around("@annotation(...Permission)")
public Object authorizeRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

 try{
   MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) jp.getSignature();
   Class<?> class = methodSignature.getDeclaringType();
   Method method = class.getDeclaredMethod(methodSignature.getName(),methodSignature.getParameterTypes());
   Permission yourCustomAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Permission.class);
   String permissionLevel = yourCustomAnnotation.permissionLevel();

   //Do your filtering based on the parameter declared per controller

   if(user has permission) {
     // Execution continues to controller
     joinPoint.proceed();
   } else {
     //Return 401 to user

   }
 }catch(Exception exception) {
 }
    
}
```